# Writing File to Temp Folder

Tags: c#, io, path

I want to use `StreamWriter` to write a file to the temp folder.

It might be a different path on each PC, so I tried using `%temp%\SaveFile.txt` but it didn't work.

How can I save to the temp folder, using environmental variables?

And for example, can I use an environmental variable for storing files in `%appdata%`?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
string result = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath

Comment: OK, Thank you very much. Where can I look for more environmental variables, such as the main hard drive, user settings and appdata?

Comment: The System.Environment class will help you get environment variables and so on. Also be sure to check out the System.Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So for the temp folder, I always have to use the Path.GetTempPath();, and for any other special path (like AppData or ProgramFiles) I have to use System.Environment?

Comment: Do you reckon varring this baby like the code example or is it OK to execute this method multiple times performance wise?

Answer (score 53):

The Path class is very useful here.
You get two methods called

[Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Path.GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

that could solve your issue

So for example you could write: (if you don't mind the exact file name)

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempFileName()))
{
    sw.WriteLine("Your error message");
}
```

Or if you need to set  your file name

```
string myTempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "SaveFile.txt");
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myTempFile))
{
     sw.WriteLine("Your error message");
}
```

Comment: the temp directory changes based on session, using RDP i logged in and accessed%TEMP% it directs to temp/2 later temp/4 ...how to get the temp folder ( not temp / digit )

Comment: Don't ask a question inside a comment on a three years old answer. Post (after a mandatory research) your own question, specifying in what is different from here

Comment: In case you don't care about the name, but do care about the extension:  `Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), "foo")`

Comment: Often easier to use `string contents = File.ReadAllText(path)` and `File.WriteAllText(path, contents)`.

Answer (score 9):

You can dynamically retrieve a temp path using as following and better to use it instead of using hard coded string value for temp location.It will return the temp folder or temp file as you want.

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),"SaveFile.txt");
```

or

```
Path.GetTempFileName();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

The path specified by the `TMP` environment variable.
The path specified by the `TEMP` environment variable.
The path specified by the `USERPROFILE` environment variable.
The Windows directory.

Answer (score 2):

For %appdata% take a look to

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Comment: Can I save it to a string variable so I don't have to rewrite this each time?

Comment: does it need any special permission for RW.. or standard user can also write on that directory ?